# How to Add customized error message in magento 2 admin form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Filed</item>
    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">model_name</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">my_custom_field</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="no-whitespace" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="validate-pattern" xsi:type="string">/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]$/i</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I want to display a customized error message in Magento 2 admin form while I use pattern validation it gives **invalid input** but I want a customized message like **You should enter a decimal value** in place of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the item as array and value. It was working on Magento 2.3.1.

```
<!-- ... -->
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="validate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="message" xsi:type="string">Custom error message for required field.</item>
    </item>
    <item name="pattern" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="validate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">/^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/i</item>
        <item name="message" xsi:type="string">Custom error message for pattern validation</item>
    </item>
</item>
<!-- ... -->
```